# javascript regex: n-times optional groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm able to match a part of the URL string to the specified format. This looks like this:

```
/foo/firstName[firstId]/optional1[oId1]/optional2[oId2]/…
```

where name[id] need to be together (like not just name or [id]) but only firstName[firstId] is mandatory and there can be up to six optional entries.

I currently match such an entry with

```
/(?:([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\])/
```

which works well standalone, as you can see [in this example](http://regex101.com/r/jL2cW2) but not with the complete URL ([example](http://regex101.com/r/zE0sD3)). In the second version, the intermediate matches are overwritten and only the last one stays.

How can I solve that problem?

**EDIT:**

Because I don't know if the dear reader understands my question, I created a simplified version.

Given the Strings:

```
/foo/x/y/z
/foo/x/y
/foo/x
```

I now want to match all three of them and to get back x, y and z.

I can use

```
^\/foo(?:\/(\w))+
```

to match the whole string. But I get only z (or only y or only x respectively) back. How do I change that?

[EXAMPLE](http://regex101.com/r/bS8jJ2)

Comment: Remove the last `+` (like you already did in the first example). Your second example is broken; the regex is different from the first, and according to 'Your regular expression explained', the 'g' flag is not set.

Comment: Thanks Ruud, but if I use the regex of the first example it doesn't work at all. So I will update the first example but the state of my question doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [example](http://regex101.com/r/zE0sD3) you just need to specify the number of occurrences you want

```
^\/foo\/(?:([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]){1,7}$
```

So, we put `{1,7}` which means minimum of 1 (the first required parameter `name`) and 6 optionals. see [regex101 test](http://regex101.com/r/fU7bH1)

---

Going beyond, if you want to match with an **URL** I think we can improve a little including this:

`^(?:(?:(?:http\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?)[^\/]*){0,1}\/foo\/(?:([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\])+`

which will put your **rule** into a real url, e.g. `www.stackoverflow.com/foo/firstName[firstId]/optional1[oId1]/optional2[oId2]/`

**edit:**

If you want to agroup **all the parameters**, so its going to be a little manually:

```
^(?:(?:(?:http\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?)[^\/]*){0,1}(?#parameter1)\/(foo)(?#parameter2)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\]))(?#optional1)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\]))?(?#optinal2)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\]))?(?#optional3)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\]))?(?#optional4)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\]))?(?#optional5)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\]))?(?#optional6)(?:\/([^\/]*\[[^\/]*\])\/?)?$
```

see [regex101 test](http://regex101.com/r/mR7nM5)

*It is not possible to do undeterminated number of groups [capturing-a-pattern-of-unknown-repitition-in-pcre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096153/capturing-a-pattern-of-unknown-repitition-in-pcre/7096175#7096175)*

Comment: I know how to use that but that not answers my problem because the intermediate match groups are still not returned. It only returns the last result of all matches.

Comment: Thanks Caio. Thats not a pleasant answer but it helps alot!

Answer (score 1):

> The intermediate matches are overwritten and only the last one stays.

A capturing group might match multiple times, but it has only one result (in JavaScript) - you're accessing the last match. Only different regex engines allow to access intermediate matches. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html.

> How do I change that?

You cannot modify the regex to give multiple results other than by adding more explicit capturing groups: `^\/foo(?:\/(\w))?(?:\/(\w))?(?:\/(\w))?(?:\/(\w))?…`. Ugly.

The easiest solution is probably to get all the parts as one long string, and then `split` them by the slash into an array:

```
> str.match(/^\/foo\/(?:[^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])+/gi)[0].split("/").slice(1);
["foo", "firstName[firstId]", "optional1[oId1]", "optional2[oId2]"]
```

If the expression is more complicated (and you have multiple capturing groups that are repeated), then you can repeatedly `exec` a regex for a single part on string and grab the groups in each iteration:

```
> var regex = /(?:([^\/\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\])/g, match;
> while (match = regex.exec(str)) console.log(match[1], match[2]);
firstName, firstId
optional1, oId1
optional2, oId2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruud's comment appears to be the ticket:
http://regex101.com/r/zQ0uO3

It doesn't eliminate the initial http folder "/foo", but you can make a small mod and/or parse it out via javascript.  It looks like a pretty good solution.